front panel audio jack 3.0 problem
in ubuntu 22.04 my front audio jack properly work. after i upgrade 24.04 it's not working. before upgrade i use pluseAudio  volume control to switch speaker to audio jack. pluseAudio volume control's output device's option select Headphones and it work. but in ubuntu 24.04 after select headphones speaker sound is off but i dont get headphone sound.
